# How to change ViewData with select onchange?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I try to change value of my viewDate (to change HTML) whith a razor select onchange

Add.cshtml.cs

```
        Severites = new SelectList(_context.Severite, "Id", "Subject");
        ViewData["Color"] = _context.Severite.FirstOrDefault().SeveriteColor;
        ViewData["Information"] = _context.Severite.FirstOrDefault().Subject; ;
        ViewData["Message"] = _context.Severite.FirstOrDefault().Message;
        return Page();
```

add.cshtml

```
            <label asp-for="Ticket.SeveriteId" class="control-label">Severité</label>
            <select asp-for="Ticket.SeveriteId" asp-items="Model.Severites" id="ddlSeve" class="form-control"></select>



            <span asp-validation-for="Ticket.SeveriteId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="card text-white bg-@ViewData["Color"] mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">@ViewData["Information"]</div>
            <div class="card-body">

                <p>
                    @ViewData["message"]
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can't you use a viewbag for the message?

Comment: Yes i can use a viewBag but when the select change how i can update this viewBag ?

Comment: actually, use a hidden filed, when the select change, put the new value on the hidden field, it is easier.

Comment: Sorry im new do you have an exemple code ?